XSD schema; In a sequence of elements, is there any way to specify, that any number of unspecified additional elements is allowed?
So, I want to write an XSD, that checks, if a list of elements contains specific required elements, but apart from them, any number of other elements is allowed, at any position of the list. Is there a way to do this? I found here, how to do it for the case, when the additional elements appear at the end:
XSD for mandatory elements followed by any additional optional elements?
But I want to allow them at any place. The order of the (required) elements is not relevant for me. If it is possible to do it with checking the order, fine, but it's not required.
For example, I want to check, that my XML contains these tags:
<HEAD>
  <thing1>Str123</thing1>
  <thing2>Str123</thing2>
  <thing3>Str123</thing3>
</HEAD>

But the HEAD element should also be able to contain any other elements at any place, say:
<HEAD>
  <thing1>Str123</thing1>
  <thing2>Str123</thing2>
  <thing4>Str123</thing4>
  <thing3>Str123</thing3>
  <thing5>Str123</thing5>
</HEAD>

I tried to combine <xsd:all> with <xsd:any> inside, but this doesn't seem to be allowed ...

I found the answer here, sorry. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528180/xsd-validation-any-in-sequence-unique-particle-attribution?rq=2

As so often, XSD 1.1 has the answer: xs:openContent mode="interleave". If your XSD processor doesn't support 1.1 (which is sadly likely), complain to your supplier and find a different product.
