# What do I need to build XML file?

Tags: xml, xsd

My client sent over a sample xml file for us to build. But the elements are not so clear, and I don't know if there is any elements that are optional, either.

Usually, we use space delimited text file to export the data, and the clients provide file layouts. For example, 
Positions 1-10: Create Date, format yyyy-mm-dd, Required
Positions 11-15: Serial Number, numeric, Required 
Positions 16-25: Memo, String, optional

But this client is asking us to generate XML file.

Is there a term to use asking "I need blue print for the XML file so I can build - meaning mapping correct field from my database to the matching elements"

When someone asks their IT vendor to create XML files, what are the usual information that is given to the IT vendor?

At first, I asked XSD file, but this is how to interpret XML files, not to build XML files.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> At first, I asked XSD file, but this is how to interpret XML files,
>   not to build XML files.

Actually, an XSD is *exactly* what you want in order to know how to build an XML file that meets the requirement of the service.  An XSD defines the vocabulary, grammar, and datatypes expected in the XML.

See also [What is the purpose of XSD files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403644/what-is-the-purpose-of-xsd-files)  In particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33686157/290085):

> **XML is all about agreement**, and XSDs provide the means for structuring
>   and communicating the agreement beyond the basic definition of XML
>   itself.