# XSD attribute size: How to shrink it programmatically

Tags: xml, xsd

Any tips on shrinking the XSD attribute size. currently my XSD has attributes with extremely long characters and I want to use a substring function to pick the last 20 characters. Am using this XSD to be imported in another tool to create a mapping xml.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The [purpose of an XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3403644/290085) is to express validity constraints on an XML document.

The purpose of XSLT is to transform one XML document to another.

Although you ask about using an XSD *to use a substring function to pick the last 20 characters*, your function is transformational, not validating.    Therefore, I'd suggest that you write XSLT based upon the identify transformation with an override for the attributes of interest that replaces the original value with one of suitably smaller size.