# Is it possible to define an attribute of an XML element to be required only if another element's attribute is set to a particular value?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I would like to ask if this is possible and if yes, how to achieve it:

For example if I have an element definition with a complexType in an XML schema definition like this:

```
<xsd:element name="tag" type="tag"/>
<xs:complexType name="tag">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="subtag" type="subtag"/>
        <xs:element name="another_subtag" type="another_subtag"/>
        <xs:element name="another_subtag_2" type="another_subtag_2"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="attr_type"/>
    <xs:attribute name="an_attr" type="an_attr"/>
    <xs:attribute name="another_attr" type="another_attr"/>
</xs:complexType name="attr_type">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
         <xsd:enumeration value="type_1"/>
         <xsd:enumeration value="type_2"/>
         <xsd:enumeration value="type_3"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
<xsd:simpleType/>
```

1) Is it possible to make the attribute '*an_attr*' of the tag element required **only** if the tag element has the attribute 'attr_type' set to 'type_2'?

And another question:
2) Is it possible to make the complexType 'tag' contain *different* child elements based again e.g. on the value of the 'attr_type'? For example for:

```
<tag attr_type="type_1">
```

have only this childs:

```
<xs:element name="subtag" type="subtag"/>
```

And for:

```
<tag attr_type="type_2">
```

have only childs:

```
 <xs:element name="another_subtag" type="another_subtag"/>
OR
 <xs:element name="another_subtag_2" type="another_subtag_2"/>
```

?

If it is possible, how can I achieve this?

Thanks for the attention!

EDIT: As I saw here -> https://blogs.oracle.com/rammenon/entry/xml_schema_11_what_you_need_to
In the example number 22 (in *Conditional Type Assignments*), could it be done in such a way?

```
<!--inline alternative type definitions --> 
<element name="TimeTravel" type="TravelType"> 
      <alternative test="@direction='Future'"> 
          <complexType> 
              <complexContent> 
              <restriction base="TravelType" 
                         .... 
<!--        some past travel related elements go here --> 
            </complexType> 
       </alternative> 
      <alternative test="@direction='Past'"> 
          <complexType> 
              <complexContent> 
              <restriction base="TravelType" 
                         .... 
   <!--        some future travel related elements go here --> 
            </complexType> 
       </alternative> 
  </element> 
                          OR 
<!--Named alternative type definitions --> 
<element name="TimeTravel" type="TravelType"> 
   <alternative test="@direction='Future' type="FutureTravelType"/> 
   <alternative test="@direction='Past' type="PastTravelType"/> 
</element>
```

As I understood it, TimeTravel element can have different complexTypes based on the direction attribute value, am I correct? But it says that XSD 1.1 must be used. Can I use this rules inside my XML Schema?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126988/restricting-xml-elements-based-on-another-element-via-xsd

Comment: So I guess I am complicating my life am I right?

Comment: Maybe but don't feel bad.  As you can tell from the link I posted in my last comment, many of us have wished XML Schema could validate elements and attributes in that way.

Comment: Yeah, anyway, please check my edit cause I think I have found an example at the link I posted in my comment to @Micheal Kay's post using Conditional Type Assignments (example 22) that is similar to this kind of problem. What do you think about this?

Comment: What edit? And when I click on your link under M.Kay's post I get '404 not found.'

Comment: I have just edited the post and put the link inside of the EDIT ;)

Comment: You are not changing complex types "contained in" TimeTravel, you are simply changing TimeTravel's own type (listed on line #1) from TravelType to either PastTravelType or FutureTravelType based on this element's own 'direction' attribute.

Comment: All right but if I change the type I can also e.g. make FutureTravelType a simpleType while I can keep PastTravelType a complexType and put or keep them both complexType and make FutureTravelType contain elements that are not in the PastTravelType and vice versa, and also make PastTravelType have attributes that are not in the FutureTravelType am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct (If I understood you correctly).  Just keep in mind that the attribute that determines all this ("direction" attribute in your example) must be an attribute of this same element, TimeTravel.

Comment: Yes I mean exactly that! Anyway, do I need to explicitly set something  in order to make my .xsd XML Schema Definition conformed to this XSD 1.1 specification or can I just keep my .xsd file as always?

Comment: Just keep it as always.  There's no requirement to label it with the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try again, since my answer has been disputed, it's probably best to give it again in more detail. Editing my original answer would make the subsequent comments incomprehensible and only add confusion.

Question 1: Is it possible to make the attribute 'an_attr' of the tag element required only if the tag element has the attribute 'attr_type' set to 'type_2'?

Answer 1: yes. You can do it like this (tested; modified from the original to avoid reference to irrelevant and undefined types):

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="tag" type="tagType">
      <xs:alternative test="@attr_type='type_2'" type="tagTypeWithMandatoryAttr"/>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="tagType">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="subtag" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="another_subtag" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="another_subtag_2" type="xs:anyType"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="an_attr" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="another_attr" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="tagTypeWithMandatoryAttr">
     <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="tagType">
          <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="subtag" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="another_subtag" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="another_subtag_2" type="xs:anyType"/>
          </xs:choice>
          <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:attribute name="an_attr" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
          <xs:attribute name="another_attr" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Question 2:

Is it possible to make the complexType 'tag' contain different child elements based again e.g. on the value of the 'attr_type'?

Answer 2:

Yes, for example (similarly tested):

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="tag" type="xs:anyType">
      <xs:alternative test="@attr_type='type_2'" type="tagType1"/>
      <xs:alternative type="tagType2"/>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="tagType1">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="subtag" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="another_subtag" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="another_subtag_2" type="xs:anyType"/>
        </xs:choice> 
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="tagType2">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="subtag" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="another_subtag" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="another_subtag_2" type="xs:anyType"/>
        </xs:choice> 
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Question 0: Is it possible to define an attribute of an XML element (E) to be required only if another element (F)'s attribute is set to a particular value?

Answer 0: it depends on the relationship of the two elements E and F. If F is an ancestor of E, then it can be done using conditional type assignment in the declaration of F. If E and F are siblings or more remotely related, then it cannot be done using conditional type assignment, but it can be done using an assertion attached to the common ancestor of E and F.

Comment: As I said, you put the conditional type assignment on the ancestor element F. It is allowed to reference its own attributes.

Comment: @MichaelKay How did you tested your XSD for validity? Do you know an online XSD 1.1 validator?

Comment: @MichaelKay Sorry, I have one more question. In your Answer 1 example  you show how the tag element can change its type depending on the value of the *attr_type* value and thus contain different elements, but where do you define the *attr_type* attribute??? E.g. if *attr_type* attribute has a simpleType with a restriction and an enumeration, where do you put it?

Comment: Testing: as the developer of the Saxon XSD 1.1 processor I don't have any problems finding a processor to test against! Declaring attr_type: it can be declared like any other attribute. I should really have included the declaration, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your response, wow! I didn't know that! So what kind of tools could you advise me to use? And where should the 'attr_type' attribute be put? Inside the 'tagType' complexType or inside the 'tagTypeWithMandatoryAttr' complexType or inside of both? I am sorry, maybe I am bothering you with this questions, but I do not mean to do it, I just want to learn! :)

Comment: If you want to use a type definition more than once, which is very often the case especially with simple types, then declare the type in a global xs:simpleType element (i.e. as a child of xs:schema, `<xs:simpleType name="attrType'>`), and refer to it where needed, e.g. `<xs:attribute name='x' type='attrType'/>`.

Comment: As regards tools, it's worth getting a license for oXygen, which gives you a choice of XSD schema validators to play with.

Comment: All right, thank you, just another question about the attr_type attribute cause I might not make the question correctly: as you declared an element `<xs:element name="tag" type="tagType">` and then tested that it has an attribute 'attr_type' set to a 'type_2' value, should the complexType *tagType* have a `<xs:attribute name="attr_type" type="attrType"/>` entry or it could be omitted? I am asking this because in you XSD you declared the element 'tag' of type tagType but then in your tagType complexType there's no 'attr_type' xs:attribute, same for tagTypeWithMandatoryAttr.

Comment: Yes, I should have included this attribute in the complexType definition.

Comment: Both tagType and tagTypeWithMandatoryAttr should incude the attribute right?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible in XSD 1.1 using the new feature of "conditional type assignment". This allows you to define the type of an element as a function of the values of its attributes.

XSD 1.1 is implemented in Altova, Saxon, and Xerces.

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you please send a reference or a link in which this argument is treated?

Comment: I found this -> https://blogs.oracle.com/rammenon/entry/xml_schema_11_what_you_need_toBut did not find an example on how to achieve it yet...

Comment: There are some good examples here: http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter14.html. For explanations of the examples, buy the book!

Comment: As this is XSD 1.1 should I put something in my .xsd file in order to use this kind of functionality? Or the xml version remains 1.0 and the xsd:schema is always the root element with its targetNamespace and other attributes?

Comment: You need to do two things: change your schema to invoke conditional type assignment (it will have an xs:alternative element), and run it using an XSD 1.1 processor. You can also signal that the schema requires XSD 1.1 using a vc:version attribute, but that's optional and largely documentary.

Comment: Hey, read the question.  You can’t “…define an attribute of an XML element to be required only if another element’s attribute is set to a particular value,” using conditional type assignment. The question asks if this attribute’s assignment can be determined by “…another element”.  Again, conditional type assignment can’t access other elements.  Period.  You should research your facts before attacking others.

Comment: @MichaelKay: this question comes up so often, perhaps you should create a canonical question/answer so they can be marked as duplicates?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Someone already did, it's posted here:;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126988/restricting-xml-elements-based-on-another-element-via-xsd and nothing in Schema version 1.1 changes the factual correctness of this answer because every bullet point in this answer states "...of any other element".

Comment: OK, I've read it more carefully. The headline question talks about attributes of "another element", and the answer to that is "no". But the specific detailed questions underneath talk about attributes of the same element, and the answer to both (1) and (2) is "yes".

Comment: OK, agreed. I can see where there may have been some confusion. I thought it was obvious that I was answering the main question at the top of the page.  Otherwise, I would have provided a multi-part answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, because conditional type assignment (mentioned in the other answer) only assigns a type to an element.  Hence the name, conditional type assignment.  Furthermore, when using conditional type assignment the element's type is determined by its own attributes and not the attributes of some other element.

Even using an XPATH expression with conditional type assignment, you can only access the attributes of the element being validated.  It cannot access its parent or ancestors, and it cannot even access its children or descendants like assertions can.

[EDIT] The main question, as posted, asked if the 1st attribute can be required based on another element's attribute's, the answer to that is no.

This would required a much higher level of validation than can be done with XML Schema 1.1.  Maybe Schematron ??? I don't know.  Sometimes the answer isn't what you want to hear.

Reference: Definitive XML Schema by Priscilla Walmsley, 2nd edition, page 378-379.

Here is [a great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126988/restricting-xml-elements-based-on-another-element-via-xsd) that sums up the countless times questions like this have been asked about XML validation.  The new additions in Schema 1.1 are very limited in scope.

Comment: Note* beginning an answer with the word “no” lowers your chances of getting up-votes by 65% (Caveat: 87% of statistics posted on the Internet are made up on the spot).

Comment: I'm not sure which question is being answered by "No", but the answer seems wrong to me. Either that, or I have misundestood the question. Conditional type assignment allows you to assign different types (i.e. validation rules) to an element based on the values of its attributes. The different types can differ both in the attributes they allow and the children (or other descendants) that they allow, and on my reading, that means the answer is Yes. So I'm downvoting this answer.

Comment: @JasonEnochs: do you know who Michael Kay is? Check his profile if you don't already know. If you _do_ already know, then Good Luck to You.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yea, I read his profile but I don’t change my viewpoints based on anything but facts. Credentials don’t make you right.  Anyone who takes the time to read the question and research conditional type assignment for themselves will determine that while Kay’s answer is factually correct, does not apply to the question posed. The answer to the question is ‘NO’.

Comment: I said "I'm not sure which question is being answered by 'No'", and I think that explains the problem; I was answering a different question from you. There are three questions here; in my latest answer I have attempted to answer all three. By the way, calling people assholes is equally offensive whether they are established experts or total beginners.