# JAXB - how to unmarshal an entity into list of entities with size 1

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following JAXB entity:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = EntityConstants.PARTNER)
public class FilePartner
{
    @XmlAttribute(name = EntityConstants.IDENTIFIER, required = true)
    private String identifier;

    @XmlElement(name = EntityConstants.NAME)
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = EntityConstants.ROOT_PATH)
    private String rootPath;

    ...
}
```

which serialized into a similar structure:

```
<file-partner identifier="foo">
    <name>bar</name>
    <root-path>path123</root-path>
    ...
</file-partner>
```

I also have an entity which represents a list of partners:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = EntityConstants.PARTNERS)
public class FilePartnerList
{

    @XmlElement(name = EntityConstants.PARTNER)
    private List<FilePartner> partners = new ArrayList<FilePartner>();

    public List<FilePartner> getPartners()
    {
        return partners;
    }

    public void addPartners(List<FilePartner> partners)
    {
        this.partners.addAll(partners);
    }
}
```

which serializes into:

```
<partners>
   <file-partner identifier="foo">
        ...
   </file-partner>
   <file-partner identifier="foo2">
        ...
   </file-partner>
   ...
</partners>
```

I am looking for a way to force the jaxb unmarshaller to deserialize XMLs in the form of

```
<file-partner identifier="foo">
        <name>bar</name>
        <root-path>path123</root-path>
        ...
</file-partner>
```

into FilePartnerList instances with list size of 1, i.e:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FilePartner.class, FilePartnerList.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
InputStream inputStream = getResourceAsStream(filePartnerAsXml);
FilePartnerList partnerList = (FilePartnerList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream); // This SHOULD be unmarshalled to FilePartnerList instead of FilePartner
assertTrue(partnerList.getPartners().getSize().equals(1));
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<FilePartner> partners = new ArrayList<FilePartner>(**1**);
```

That way you'll get a fixed size input array....

But I'm sure that you will want to get the XSD of that model with the 'maxocurrs=1' so you will end modifying the XSD manually.

Anyway: why don't you, if the list size must be fixed to '1', simply set it as a simple node with a single child? Something like this (untested):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = EntityConstants.PARTNERS)
public class FilePartnerList
{

    @XmlElement(name = EntityConstants.PARTNER)
    private FilePartner partners;

    public FilePartner getFilePartner()
    {
        return partner;
    }

    public void setPartner(FilePartner partner)
    {
        this.partner = partner;
    }
}
```

This way you will have one and only one partner per parnets-list.

The XML that fullfits the XSD of your service a text and in that text is indistinguible a list with max size 1 and a node.

Comment: I was misunderstood. 
Using a fixated size in the FilePartnerList is not possible because I still might need to unmarshal <partners> that contain more than 1 <file-partner> children.
What I wish is that if I happen to have some XML that contains just a single <file-partner> tag (not surrounded by <partners> parrent) then it should be unmarshalled into a FilePartnerList with size 1

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067873/is-it-possible-to-define-an-attribute-of-an-xml-element-to-be-required-only-if-a I would do a valid xsd with that choices and make the java classes with xjc...