# Value based conditional restriction in XSD 1.0

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.0

Below is my sample XML:

```
  <RootElement attributeName="Value1">
    <ChildElement>0</ChildElement>
    <ChildElement>1</ChildElement>
    <ChildElement>2</ChildElement>
    <ChildElement>3</ChildElement>
  </RootElement>
```

I want to add restriction based on value of attributeName. Value of attributeName can be Value1|Value2|Value3. If the value of attribute name is Value1 or Value2 then no child element should be present. If the value of attribute name is Value3 then there should be min 1 and max 15 ChildElement occurrences.
I want to achieve this with XSD v1.0. I found some solutions with XSD v1.1 but I can't use them because I want to achieve this in XSD v1.0.
I found some solutions with abstract and choice but with that it provide different child elements names. I can have only "ChildElement". I can't use other child elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126988/restricting-xml-elements-based-on-another-element-via-xsd/4141569#4141569

Comment: If I have to use XSD v1.0 then what will be changes required in .Net application to process XSD v1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of restriction is not possible with XSD 1.0. You can achieve same by using Assert or Rule in XSD 1.1 or later.