# XSD File and Export

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am new to XSD. I want to know how XSD files are used to export data to XML.

I assume that same XSD file can be used while imorting the XML file to check if the schema of the XML file is as per the schema of XSD file. I hope this assumption is correct.

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSD files are used to check the schema of the XML:

```
XmlReaderSettings xmlSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
xmlSettings.Schemas.Add("http://www.example.com/SchemaName", 
    "http://intranet/xml/schemadatei.xsd");
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(this.dateiname, xmlSettings);
while (xmlReader.Read())
{ }
```

And you can generate from XSD a class as you can see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Some corrections in your statement:
XSD file doesn't export the data .. **it is used to validate the data.**
XSD file can be used to validate XML while importing it .. so as to check if XML file is **as per the SCHEMA file.** XSD-XML Schema Definition

> ps: Normal convention is .. XSD is used on imported data than
>   exporting ones.. because you know what you are sending .. but you
>   should be sure enough to accept the valid data that is sent to you by
>   other system.. (no harm in validating out-going data though)

- XML stands for EXtensible Markup Language
- XML is a markup language
  much like HTML (but not HTML)
- XML was designed to carry data, (not to
  display data)
- No tags or attributes are predefined. What you define
  is your data :)

The purpose of an XML Schema is to define rule-sets for an XML document, just like a DTD.
(its much more advanced than DTD.)
Refer this link [[click_here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2339660/215234) to know capabilities and limits of XSD