# How to retrieve data from oracle database in XSD format?

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, xsd, ojdbc

in the Oracle database I have a table which contains simple attributes such as:

`name` `first name` `age`

#### Goal: I would like to recover this data in XSD format.

are there SQL functions for that or java libraries that do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results to clarify your requirement.

Comment: Do you mean in XML format or do you really mean XSD format?

Comment: Xml or xsd format, if you had a solution, i'll take it.

Comment: You can't just say "XML or XSD, ... I'll take it" they may both be XML documents but they fulfil a very different function. One contains data (XML) and one describes how the data should be structured (XSD).

Answer (score 3):

XSD stands for [XML Schema Definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333998/what-is-the-difference-between-xml-and-xsd) and is used to describe an XML document's structure, constraints, data types. So you would put data in an XML document but the structure/format of that document (without any data) would be described by an associated XSD.

Since you are talking about data, you probably want an XML document (and not an XSD) and can use [Oracle's XML functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB1620):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( first_name, last_name, date_of_birth ) AS
SELECT 'Alice', 'Adams', DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl', 'Booth', DATE '1980-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', 'Cross', DATE '1990-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT XMLELEMENT(
         "People",
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT( 
           "Person",
             XMLFOREST(
               first_name AS "FirstName",
               last_name  AS "LastName",
               EXTRACT( YEAR FROM ( SYSDATE - date_of_birth ) YEAR TO MONTH ) AS "Age"
             )
           )
         )
       ) AS XML
FROM   table_name
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | XML                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <People><Person><FirstName>Alice</FirstName><LastName>Adams</LastName><Age>50</Age></Person><Person><FirstName>Beryl</FirstName><LastName>Booth</LastName><Age>40</Age></Person><Person><FirstName>Carol</FirstName><LastName>Cross</LastName><Age>30</Age></Person></People> |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=46c0bc1984b0ff051e698f792d119ceb)*

If you really want to generate an XSD then you can do that using the same functions as an XSD is, itself, an XML document; but its not something you put data into.

Comment: Thanks for your response but what if i dont know the content of my table ? Or i have Many tables? Is there a more simple way ?

Comment: @H_A_92s7 Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25201287) your question to give us more details of what you are actually asking. You say in the question that you have a table and give us fields that are in there and then you say in the comment above that you don't know what columns/table you have; which is it? And what do you mean a more simple way? The SQL query above is about as simple as you are going to get for generating a single XML document.