# Must you specify namespace in XSD for it to be valid?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xml-validation

I was reading up on XSD in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333998/what-is-the-difference-between-xml-and-xsd) where I saw [this tool](http://xsd2xml.com/) mentioned in the accepted answer comments. I went on to read the [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333998/what-is-the-difference-between-xml-and-xsd#answer-2339660) and tried out their example.

I did not understand how the suggested XSD had no problems without including the line:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Is this the default behavior? Here's the proposed XSD for easier reading:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="parent">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="child_one" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="child_two" type="xs:int" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

==Addition by MHK (because I can edit the post, but can't add a comment) ==

Deleting a post because you now know where you went wrong is inappropriate. That's not the way StackOverflow works.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. It does contain the required namespace declaration.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I missed it. I will close the question. I didn't realize that you could have it at the end. Thought it needed to be in the beginning.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I got your edit. I undeleted it. Thanks.